# Is it better to spread out RAM on multiple sticks or less

Tags: memory, desktop-computer, computer-building

I am building a new desktop computer. I will be using 128GB of RAM. I know that is a lot, I am not interested in explaining why I need it. My question is how I should plan this out. I have 8 ports for RAM, Should I buy 8 16GB RAM sticks or one 128 GB stick. Other variances of 128 GB are also an option. However, I am basicly wanting to know if its better to spread it all out or consolidate.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you even get 128GB RAM modules?? I know you can get 32GB ones, so either 8x16GB or 4x32GB would work. The latter allows future expansion if you need to double up, the former is probably cheaper. The most important thing is to check the QVL for your motherboard to make sure it supports the RAM you buy (memory timings, size, etc.) - it may not even support 32GB or larger sticks depending on the board.

Comment: It depends on your motherboard.  If it support Quad channel memory then that is your best option.  If it support dual channel, then 2 unless it supports 2 banks of dual channel.  Dual doubles, Quad is 4x the memory width so memory read/write speeds will be double or quadrupled.

Comment: Building a new desktop computer. You mean building a server? I can't think of any computer that would come close to using that much. It would be best to use all of you RAM slots. Using a single stick would not allow memory channeling technology to be used.

Comment: I'd definitely check what sticks it can take. Mine will take 8 x 8GB for 64GB or 6 x 16GB for 96GB [dual or triple channel]. It will not take 128GB.